# EF Core - Hardcoded Foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, annotations

I am trying to work out how to add a reference an object from within EF.

I little hard to explain so I thought I would share a dotnetfiddle example
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4n5Flk

```
public class ReportConfig
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReportConfigKey {get; set;}
        public int ConfigTypeKey {get; set;}
        public int ConfigValue {get; set;}
        
        [ForeignKey("ConfigTypeKey")]
        public virtual <ConfigType> ConfigType {get; set;}
    
    }
    
    public class ConfigType
    {
       [Key]
        public int ConfigTypeKey {get; set;}
        
        //This can be
        //Address
        //Car etc etc.
        public string ConfigName {get; set;}
    }
    
    public class Car
    {
        [Key]
        public int CarId {get; set;}
        //other items
    }
    
    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public AddressId {get; set;}
    }
```

In a nutshell I am trying to create a navigation property to either a car or an address based on the ConfigValue and the ConfigTypeKey

I was thinking to create 2 navigation properties "Car" and "Address" and for both add 2 foreign key's 1 to the object and 1 as a hardcoded reference to ConfigName as Car or Address

is this possible atall

Sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: You are using Entity which has a mapping file that links the database table to the c# classes.   So for your idea to work you need the tables in the database and the mapping files for the table.  In the code <ConfigType> is a table in the database.

Comment: these are all tables in the database presently, but the problem, is the Configvalue can represent different objects based on ConfigTypeKey

Comment: ConfigValue in this example would represent either AddressId or CarId

Comment: A list of AddressID or CarId are in a table and marked as a Primary Key.

Comment: they are as a [Key] to match the the DB, the problem is have is defining them within the classes above.

Comment: How are you doing the Mapping?  The mapping is in the edmx file and the mapping has to match the c# classes.